# duplicate a product attribute into a new field in admin interface?

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

Is it possible to duplicate a product attribute into a new field -- using only Magento's admin interface ?

Creating a PHP script or using a SQL statement is not an option ( I wish it were ).  I need a solution that is entirely done on the dashboard.

Example:

We need to duplicate the "SKU" attribute into a new "UPC" attribute.  [ about 100 products will then be hand-edited to remove invalid UPCs ]

I know I could do this quickly in PHP or the Database.  I would honestly prefer that -- but this is for a friend who has no in-house tech talent right now.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can use Import/Export. This is somewhat done in the admin panel. However, I do not believe that there is a "admin-only" way to duplicate attributes (other than manual, copy and paste).

1. Ensure attribute is there to duplicate attribute value into
2. Navigate to System -> Import/Export -> Export.
3. Export the product database.
4. Load into Excel
5. Copy new attribute value and make necessary adjustments
6. Remove all columns except for SKU, and the duplicate attribute value
7. Save Excel spreadsheet as a CSV
8. Navigation to System -> Import/Export -> Import and load back in the CSV file
9. Check the process worked.